# Animate UserControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, user-controls

I have two xaml file one is **MainWindow.xaml** and other is userControl **EditTaskView.xaml**.
In MainWindow.xaml it consists of listbox and when double clicked any item of listbox, it displays other window (edit window) from EditView userControl. I am trying to animate this userControl everytime whenever any item from the listbox is double clicked. I added some animation in userControl however the animation only gets run once. How can i make my animation run everytime whenever any item from the listbox is clicked?

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lstBxTask"   Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItems}" MouseDoubleClick="lstBxTask_MouseDoubleClick">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>               
            <DataTemplate>                    
                <StackPanel>
                    <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource LineBetweenListBox}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Taskname}"  Style="{StaticResource TextInListBox}"/>
                        <Button Name="btnDelete" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButton}" Click="btnDelete_Click"/>                                                      
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>  
    <ToDoTask:EditTaskView x:Name="EditTask" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

In the MainWindow code, there is mouse double click event, which changes the visibility of EditTaskView to Visible.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us your animation. Usually the animation **does** play everytime the event is triggered:

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFB62A2A"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="#FF2A32B6"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseDoubleClick">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bitbonk, your code really help.

I think i figure out what was my problem. I had EventTrigger as FrameworkElement.Loaded instead of Control.MouseDoubleClick.

anyway the code looks like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="AnimateEditView">
        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="EditTask">
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="0"/>
        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="EditTask">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

<Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource headerAnimation}"/>
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource textBxAnimation}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Control.MouseDoubleClick">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimateEditView}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
```